# h1 not aligning to center without enough text underneath

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-4

My `h1` only aligns to the center of the screen if it has enough text underneath it. Otherwise, it will align wrong/not at all. How do I fix this?

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}

.textbox {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 100px 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container textbox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are my screenshots of what happens in each situation I mentioned:

[No text underneath the h1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grpzz.png)

[A bit of text underneath the h1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2fKD.png)

[Enough text underneath the h1 (the h1 finally aligns properly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ0dC.png)

Comment: Show your markup with the extra text so we know what you're doing.

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me in IE11; `<h1>` aligns even with no text underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no need for any custom css for simple things of this nature in Bootstrap 4. The `text-center` class is what you want for your h1.

Also, the `col-xs-*` class doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4 anymore. It's just `col-*` now.

Here's a working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="text-center">Contact</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use those tips in the future ;)